# converting c# float to IEEE single precision floating point bytes

Tags: c#, floating-point

I am implementing [RFC4506](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506) (XDR) in c#.
Does the binary format for floats in c# (`BitConverter.GetBytes`) use the IEEE standard?

How would I convert a **float in c#** into the XDR **binary format** for an  **IEEE** single precision floating point number, I could do the legwork manually, but I would like to know if there *is an existing method to do this?*

The standard defines the floating-point data type "float" (32 bits or
4 bytes).  The encoding used is the IEEE standard for normalized
single-precision floating-point numbers [IEEE].  The following three
fields describe the single-precision floating-point number:

```
  S: The sign of the number.  Values 0 and 1 represent positive and
     negative, respectively.  One bit.

  E: The exponent of the number, base 2.  8 bits are devoted to this
     field.  The exponent is biased by 127.

  F: The fractional part of the number's mantissa, base 2.  23 bits
     are devoted to this field.
```

Therefore, the floating-point number is described by:

```
     (-1)**S * 2**(E-Bias) * 1.F
```

the exact layout is as follows.

```
     +-------+-------+-------+-------+
     |byte 0 |byte 1 |byte 2 |byte 3 |              SINGLE-PRECISION
     S|   E   |           F          |         FLOATING-POINT NUMBER
     +-------+-------+-------+-------+
     1|<- 8 ->|<-------23 bits------>|
     <------------32 bits------------>
```

Just as the most and least significant bytes of a number are 0 and 3,
the most and least significant bits of a single-precision floating-
point number are 0 and 31.  The beginning bit (and most significant
bit) offsets of S, E, and F are 0, 1, and 9, respectively.  Note that
these numbers refer to the mathematical positions of the bits, and
NOT to their actual physical locations (which vary from medium to
medium).

Comment: Isn't `float` a [single precision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) by itself?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Hans you legend, that's the answer I needed, do you want to post it as the answer? I was not keen to spend the rest of friday afternoon shifting bits and writing tests for them :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET uses IEEE representation as well so `BitConverter.GetBytes` gets you the bytes you need.

It is however a half-baked standard, it only specifies the bit interpretation but does not demand a physical representation.  The RFC is infected with Unix preferences from the previous century, like all networking standards are, byte order is big-endian.

On most any machine that can run .NET you need to reverse the bytes.  Thus:

```
public static byte[] XdrFloat(float value) {
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```